# How can i retrieve chat history from mysql db using smack client ejabberd

Tags: android, mysql, chat, smack

I am implementing Android one to one chat using **ejabberd**. I have enabled `mod_mam` modules in ejabberd config file. Now I am able to store chat in `mysql` DB. But I am unable to retrieve chat history. I am using **smack library** in my android application.
I googled my problem but could not found any solution.
Can anyone tell me a solution?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I worte the below method to get archived messages using smack form mysql. 
 It returns the last `maxResults` results from DB. 
 The below code basically utilizes existing library methods to fetch retults.

```
public MamManager.MamQueryResult getArchivedMessages(String jid, int maxResults) {

    MamManager mamManager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    try {
        DataForm form = new DataForm(DataForm.Type.submit);
        FormField field = new FormField(FormField.FORM_TYPE);
        field.setType(FormField.Type.hidden);
        field.addValue(MamElements.NAMESPACE);
        form.addField(field);

        FormField formField = new FormField("with");
        formField.addValue(jid);
        form.addField(formField);

        RSMSet rsmSet = new RSMSet(maxResults, "", RSMSet.PageDirection.before);
        MamManager.MamQueryResult mamQueryResult = mamManager.page(form, rsmSet);

        return mamQueryResult;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

To get this in a paginated way use below function

```
 public MamManager.MamQueryResult getMessageBefore(String jid, String messageId) {

    MamManager mamManager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    try {
        MamManager.MamQueryResult mamQueryResult = 
          mamManager.pageBefore(JidCreate.bareFrom(jid), messageId, pageSize);
        return mamQueryResult;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return null;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: MamQueryResult is deprecated in smack 4.3.0 what is an alternative. Can you share a code snippet for my quick reference